# Python Commandline script: file/directory autocompletion on user input

Tags: python, command-line

I'm writing a Python program which is running inside a Bash Terminal (and it already depends on Bash as its environment).
There I have a little setup routine, which asks the user for a directory which is located on his filesystem.
This is how I read the input:

```
print "Input:",
input = sys.stdin.readline().strip()
```

Now I want the user to be able to autocomplete his input with the name of existing files or directories. What's the best way to do that? Do I need to lookup the directories/files myself and use the package `cmd` (as in [this example](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/cmd.html))? Or is there an easier, "built-in" way to do that?

It would also be ok if i was able to use the Bash autocompletion with os.system. But everything that i tried so far wasn't successful. This is what I tried:

```
os.system("read -e -p \"Input:\" INPUT")
```

But it's strange: Bash complains `read: 1: Illegal option -e`, although the command works inside a simple Bash script. But I need the -e modifier for the completion.

Any suggestions how I can do file/dirname autocompletion in an Python Console Program?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to checkout the [readline module](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html).  I answered a [similar question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input/5638688#5638688), which shows how to do filename/dirname auto-completion of paths. Let me know if you need more detail.

Comment: Your example does exactly what I need inside `complete_extra`. Also nice that it's not dependent on Bash (although it doesn't matter that much). Will adapt this for my own script. Thanks!