# filepath autocompletion using users input

Tags: python, bash, input, autocomplete

(python)

I'm looking to grab a users input for a filepath. It seems pretty basic, but I can't seem to get readline or rlcompleter working.

Pretty much:
variable = raw_input(' Filepath: ')    and then the filepath has autocomplete functions like it would in a shell.

I'm not restricted to python, I'm willing to use any language so long as I can set a variable as the filepath and grab the filepath using  autocomplete functionality.

I've seen this:  [Tab completion in Python's raw_input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input)   which helped me get an idea of what to look for, although the problem was that it required a command in front of the filepath such as "extra". I need to set the variable as the filepath. You'd think it'd be pretty simple, but I haven't found much on it anywhere, and the few that I have found weren't exactly what I was looking for.

In bash there was a read -e command that can be run in a command line, but it's not recognized in a script which was odd. It's exactly what I was looking for, if only it could be utilized inside of a script to set the variable equal to the autocompleted filepath.

Comment: do you mean you would like to implement tilde-expansion, file-name-globbing, shell-variable expansion etc? Pls, add expected input...

Answer (score 29):

Something like this?

```
import readline, glob
def complete(text, state):
    return (glob.glob(text+'*')+[None])[state]

readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n;')
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
readline.set_completer(complete)
raw_input('file? ')
```

Comment: This implementation of a completer is inferior to the default one in that it doesn't seem to properly complete paths outside the current directory. But thank you nevertheless for the interesting piece'o'code.

Comment: This does not seem to work for relative (ie `../<TAB>')` or `~/<TAB>`. Does anyone know why?

Comment: out-of-cwd completion works for me on OSX :)
but colours in the output doesnt :(

Comment: To get it working with ~ you have to use `glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(text)+'*')`
About relative path you have to define your own list of delimiters not containing '/' (default is `\t\n \`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:\'",<>/?`)

Answer (score 1):

This is only loosely python and I suspect there are probably ways that someone could hack this and cause you all kinds of problems... or something but this is a way I got the bash and python to play well together.

```
import subprocess

the_file=subprocess.check_output('read -e -p "Enter path file:" var ; echo $var',shell=True).rstrip()
```