# Cmd module '~' completion

Tags: python, cmd, tab-completion, tilde

I have been playing around with the cmd python module and was looking at the text completion function. I have been trying to get it to expand/recognise '~' to my home directory but with no avail.

I've noticed that I can handle default completion by overriding the `completedefault(self, *ignored)` method from the cmd module. Where `ignored` is a tuple of the text, line, begidx, endidx. If I type in the command `my_command ./folder` the `text` parameter will be './folder' and this mean I can do something like: `glob.glob(text + '*')` which returns a list of all the files in that folder. However, if I now do `my_command ~/folder` the `text` variable now only contains `/folder`, so I am unable to use `os.path.expanduser(text)` to determine the absolute path of that folder and show all the files in that folder.

Basically I am wondering if someone could point me in the right direction in order to expand  paths with a `~` in it.

Comment: You need to isolate the thing of interest. `expanduser('~/folder')` will give you what you want. Could you use `begidx`/`endidx`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Expanding on the answer from: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6657975/1263565

You could override the cmd module's [`completedefault()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/cmd.html#cmd.Cmd.completedefault) method with:

```
def completedefault(self, *ignored):
        # Set the autocomplete preferences
        readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n;')
        readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
        readline.set_completer(complete)
```

with the complete method looking like:

```
def complete(text, state):
    return (glob.glob(os.path.expanduser(text)+'*')+[None])[state]
```

This should now allow `~` expansion.