# How to use the bash command 'read -e variable' and pass the variable to a python variable

Tags: python, bash, variables, autocomplete

I'd like to pass shell input to a variable in python. Normally I would use the `raw_input()` method for this, but I'd like to use something which allows me to "browse" through my folders.

In a bash script I'd use something like this: (The -e allows me use the "autocomplete" function of the shell via Tab.)

```
#!/bin/bash

echo Please input the path to the file:

read -e var

echo $var
```

Does anyone know how to solve this in Python? I looked at `os.popen()` and `os.system()` but cannot figure out how to use them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [readline](http://docs.python.org/library/readline.html) module can give you tab completion for raw_input().

You probably want to do something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5638688/1460976).

Comment: Hey thx for your help. After all, I used a bash script which asks for the path and then opens my python script. This way, it was easier for me to handle and know what is going on.