# arguments passing through command line in python

Tags: python, python-2.7

this question may be a foolish question. since im new to this python , please help me in this issue.

```
if __name__== '__main__' :
    path=sys.argv[1]
```

in the above code im reading arguments from command line. my argument is a path to some file in system. when i dont give argumentts it is raising a error "list index out of range"

instead of reading from command line
i want to take input in the following manner

> " enter path to your file.."

after showing this line 
how can i parse through the file system by pressing tab and take path as input?

Comment: you need to add a check if cmdline arguments are passed if not use raw_input or input to ask for the same

Comment: in raw_input or input i have to write correct path. but i want to select the folders by pressing tab @avasal

Comment: For make things clear, what you want is to ask the user to enter the path, but not to force him to write it completely by hand, helping him with the terminal-completion by pressing TAB?

Answer (score 2):

`sys.argv` is simply a list, by saying `sys.argv[1]` its the same as saying `args = [0]; args[1]` You need to check that index `1` actually exists

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
path = raw_input("enter path to your file..")

print path
```

If you are using commandline arguments like `hello.py myfile.txt`, then use

```
if len(sys.argv) > 1:
    path = sys.argv[1]
```

Update:

If you need to show to the user all the files in a directory. Use this:

```
import os

i = 1

for item in os.listdir("F:/python/Lib"):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join("F:/python/Lib", item)):
        print str(i) + " : " + item
        i += 1
```

Output:

```
>>> 
1 : abc.py
2 : abc.pyc
3 : aifc.py
4 : antigravity.py
5 : anydbm.py
6 : argparse.py
7 : ast.py
8 : asynchat.py
9 : asyncore.py
10 : atexit.py
11 : atexit.pyc
12 : audiodev.py
13 : base64.py
14 : base64.pyc
15 : BaseHTTPServer.py
16 : BaseHTTPServer.pyc
17 : Bastion.py
18 : bdb.py
19 : bdb.pyc
```

Comment: by this i cant parse through the file structure. i dont want to hard core the path of the file. i want to choose from the folders shown when i press tab key.

Comment: For that, you will need something like `filepicker` : http://pypi.python.org/pypi/filepicker/0.1.0

Comment: this is not what i want. you are not getting me.

Comment: Are you in Windows or linux?

Comment: What OP wants is to ask the user to enter the path, but not to force him to write it completely by hand, helping him with the terminal-completion.

Answer (score 0):

> how can i parse through the file system by pressing tab and take path as input

This is not an easy task, since your *pressing tab* implies the completion, which is done at `bash` or `batch` level (the terminal on which you are running your python program).

You might need to add a function which calls the appropriate subroutines from the `os` and `sys` module, and do a custom completion.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input) you can find an idea of what I mean, hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

*Something somehow less relevant*:

If you would like to perform more sophisticated command line options parsing, consider using the `argparse` [module](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html).

This is a simple demonstration of the module in a script I made:

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='MD5 Cracker')
parser.add_argument('target', metavar='Target_MD5_Hash', help='The target MD5 that you want to have cracked.')
parser.add_argument('--online', '-o', help='MD5 Cracker will try to crack the password using online MD5 cracking websites and databases', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--list', '-l', help='MD5 Cracker will try to crack the passwork offline with a dictionary attack using the list supplied', default=False)
parser.add_argument('--interactive', '-i', help='MD5 Cracker will enter interactive mode, allowing you to check passwords without reinitiating the software each time', default=False)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli_args = parser.parse_args()
    args_dict = cli_args.__dict__ # here it is cast into a dictionary to allow for easier manipulation of contents
```