# Directory suggestions while running python script

Tags: python, bash, autocomplete, directory

While working with bash if you use some commands like '$cd Home/Downloads' , you can get directory suggestions (i.e. autocomplete) based on the directory you are in and moving into.

I wanted to have similar directory suggestions while I run a python script. Currently I take user input in form of a string of directory path and then use that path in my program.

But doing this is not user friendly and also has scope of error since user is not very sure of exact string which should be given. If I could somehow make autocomplete suggestions then it would be foolproof and also intuitive.

What are the options ?

Comment: Are you trying to autocomplete filename? or a string? filenames does autocomplete in bash automatically, even in PowerShell and command prompt.

Comment: trying to autocomplete/ suggest directory

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab completion in Python's raw\_input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input)