# Is there a path-prompt in python

Tags: python, terminal, console, command-prompt

If I direct to a directory with only one index.htm file in it and I use my console and type `nano inde`, and press the tab-key, it completes it to `nano index.htm`.

In python, there is the default-prompt `raw_input("Enter some text!")` and getpass offers a password-prompt `getpass.getpass("Enter your password!")`, but is there also a path-prompt as described?

Comment: See the [readline](https://docs.python.org/2/library/readline.html) module

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Tab completion in Python's raw\_input()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input)