# Exercism.io automation with pytest and version control

Tags: python, bash, git, continuous-integration, pytest

CI newbie here. I'm currently working on the python track for [Exercism.io](http://exercism.io). I'm looking for a way to automate the process of running tests from pytest, committing and pushing to github, and finally submitting to exercism if all tests pass. I've implemented a pre-commit hook to invoke tests on commit but I'm not sure how to pass the filename back to exercism for submission. Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put together a solution for anyone else looking for a similar workflow. It utilizes a python script in the root directory and handles the git commands via subprocess. It also supports autocomplete for the file directory (based on [this gist](https://gist.github.com/iamatypeofwalrus/5637895)). This script assumes you've already initialized the git repo and setup your remote repo as well.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pytest
import subprocess
import readline
import glob

class tabCompleter(object):
    """ 
    A tab completer that can complete filepaths from the filesystem.

    Partially taken from:
    http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5637124/tab-completion-in-pythons-raw-input
    """

    def pathCompleter(self,text,state):
        """ 
        This is the tab completer for systems paths.
        Only tested on *nix systems
        """
        return [x for x in glob.glob(text+'*')][state]

if __name__=="__main__":
    # Take user input for commit message
    commit_msg = raw_input('Enter the commit message: ')

    t = tabCompleter()

    readline.set_completer_delims('\t')

    # Necessary for MacOS, Linux uses tab: complete syntax
    if 'libedit' in readline.__doc__:
        readline.parse_and_bind("bind ^I rl_complete")
    else:
        readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")

    #Use the new pathCompleter
    readline.set_completer(t.pathCompleter)

    #Take user input for exercise file for submission
    ans = raw_input("Select the file to submit to Exercism: ")

    if pytest.main([]) == 0:
        """
        If all tests pass: 
        add files to index,
        commit locally,
        submit to exercism.io,
        then finally push to remote repo.
        """
        subprocess.call(["git","add","."])
        subprocess.call(["git","commit","-m", commit_msg])
        subprocess.call(["exercism","submit",ans])
        subprocess.call(["git","push","origin","master"])
```