# How to make a Python script "tab-complete" directories in terminal?

Tags: python, python-3.x, shell, terminal, subprocess

I have a Shell Script, let's say `run.sh`, which reads a user input from keyboard and then does some specific tasks. For some technical reasons I'm migrating this script to Python, e.g `run.py`, in order to achieve the exact same goal.

In the `run.sh` file I ask the user a input, which is typically a file in the file system, so I gave the option of "tab-completing" it and I achieved it simply through the line:

`read -e -p "Choose a file: " file`

The `-e` flag does the job of tab-completing users input. For example, if user's current directory is `project`, which follows the structure:

```
project
-- src
-- shared
   -- lib
   -- imgs
      -- image.png
-- include
-- README.txt
```

and the input file is `image.png` they could proceed as follow:

`sh<tab>i<tab><tab>`

the result would be `shared/imgs/image.png`.

Now how do I achieve it inside a Python script? You may believe there are tons of related questions but I haven't been able to reproduce this exact same result in `run.py`.

What I have tried so far:

**1. Python's `os` module:**

```py
import os

os.system("read -e -p 'Choose a file:'")
```

Output: `sh: 1: read: Illegal option -e`

**2. Python's `subprocess` module**

```py
import subprocess

subprocess.run(['read', '-e', '-p', 'Choose a file'])
```

Output:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "run.py", line 26, in <module>
    subprocess.run(['read', '-e', '-p', 'Choose a file'])
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 453, in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 756, in __init__
    restore_signals, start_new_session)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.7/subprocess.py", line 1499, in _execute_child
    raise child_exception_type(errno_num, err_msg, err_filename)
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'read': 'read'
```

**3. Python's `readline` module**

```py
import readline

readline.parse_and_bind("tab:complete")
file = input("Choose a file: ")
```

This one almost seems to work, but there is one big issue: it completes only the files in user's current directory. If user hit `s<tab>` then `src` and `shared` show up, but if they hit `sh<tab>` the `lib`and `imgs` directory do not show up.

I'd like some elegant and simple way to achieve this, but I am convinced this might be a little more difficult than expected. Are there any other approaches that can solve this problem?

Comment: The reason why your tries #1 and #2 failed is that `read` is a shell built-in command, not an actual executable file on disk.  (It HAS to be a built-in, because it otherwise couldn't set a shell variable with its result.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set sensible completion delimiters:

```
import readline

readline.set_completer_delims(' \t\n=')
readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")
option = input("Tab complete a file: ")
```

By default, `readline` will delimit based on any of the following:

```
>>> import readline
>>> readline.get_completer_delims()
' \t\n`~!@#$%^&*()-=+[{]}\\|;:\'",<>/?'
```

Since `/` is part of this set, anything after a `/` will be completed independently of anything before it. This obviously makes no sense when you're trying to complete a file path.

Comment: Thanks, this is exactly what I was looking for. To also reach files with spaces I set `readline.set_completer_delims('\t\n=')`